# Expressing the instance of a ZF Set Theory axiom for a given property

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, set-theory, axioms, logic-translation

I am currently in the process of studying **ZF Set Theory (without the Axiom of Choice)** and I have come across a type of question that is unclear to me. The basic format of the question is to "express the instance of a given axiom for a particular property".

For example an example of this type of question would be:

> Without using abbreviations, only using logical symbols and the relation symbols =, ∈ only). Express:
>
> - the instance of the Axiom Schema of Separation for the property “$x$ is not a singleton”
> - the instance of the Axiom Schema of Separation for the property “$x$ is transitive”

Now of course I am familiar with the properties of a set being a singleton or a set being transitive. Equally, I am also familiar with the Axiom Schema of Separation. However, what I'm not sure is exactly what this type of question actually means. I can certainly state the formal definitions of these properties and the Axiom of Separation - but it seems to suggest that I am supposed to deduce some relationship between the two.

What is the question really asking and how do I answer this type of question?

Comment: Maybe they're just asking you to write something like $\{x \in A \mid \operatorname{singleton}(x)\}$, only with $\operatorname{singleton}(x)$ written out. I'm not sure either exactly what is being asked for. ETA: Or perhaps you need something like $\forall A \exists B \forall x( x \in B \Leftrightarrow x \in A \wedge \operatorname{singleton}(x))$.

Comment: They're specifically referencing the Axiom Schema of Separation though. If they just wanted it written out in that way, wouldn't it make more sense for it to just ask the question: "Express the set of all singletons in the language of Set Theory"? @BrianTung

Comment: Possibly what's in my edit? ETA: That's not the set of all singletons. It's the set of all singletons in an arbitrary set $A$ (therefore an unquantified predicate). My edit suggests a possible quantification.

Comment: The collection of all singletons *isn't* a set. It's too big. The Axiom Schema of Separation only gives subsets of other sets.

Comment: P.S. Oops, I only now saw that it says "*not* a singleton" [emphasis added].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll do the first one.

> **Axiom Schema of Seperation:** For y not free in the formula φ:
>
> $$ ∀x∃y∀z(z∈y ↔ (z∈x) \land φ) $$
>
> And similarly, we also have:
>
> **"z is not a singleton":**
> $$∀a(\{ a \} ≠ z) $$

Now let $\phi = \forall a (\{a \} \neq z)$. Where z ≠ y.  So, the instance of the Axiom Schema with our φ is:

$$∀x∃y∀z(z∈y ↔ z∈x \land ∀a(\{a\} ≠ z)) $$

In English, for any set $x$ and $y ≠ z$, (otherwise $y$ would be a free variable), we have that $y = \{z∈x | ∀a(\{a\} ≠ z)\}$ is a set.

(i.e. $y ⊆ x$ and the elements of $y$ are not singletons).

Comment: I believe $$∀x∃y∀z((z∈y ↔ z∈x) \land (∀a(\{a\} ≠ b))  $$ should be $$\forall x\exists y \forall z (z\in y \leftrightarrow (z\in x \land \forall a(\{a\}\ne b))) $$. Also $b$ is unbound here, so it is not an axiom.

Comment: thanks!! good catch !